# Unix(FreeBSD) - how to get real clock per sec

Tags: c, unix, posix, freebsd

Anybody knows, how to get real value of clock per sec? `clock()` from `time.h` returns clocks from start of my process, so it need to be divided by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, but this constant has always value `1000000`.

Is there some POSIX standard for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it specified in the C specification.

If you want to measure elapsed time, there are other (and better) functions, like [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) for example.